# Get functions selectors of contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, assembly, yul, function-selector

Is it possible to get all the function selectors from a contract using only Solidity and/or assembly?

Thanks!

Comment: not exactly an answer to this question but may be of interest
https://louisabraham.github.io/articles/no-abi.html

Comment: Thanks! With a web3 lib is rather easy. The tricky part is doing it with solidity @sola24